# Varnish maximum "set beresp.ttl" value

Tags: varnish

I'm trying to set 100 days = 144000m ttl for varnish cache for a certain page but I observed Varnish is purging cached pages.

So question what is the maximum ttl that I can set

```
if ((req.url ~ "\.(html)$") && (beresp.ttl > 0s)) {
   unset beresp.http.cache-control;
   unset beresp.http.expires;
   unset beresp.http.cookie;
   set beresp.do_gzip = true;
   set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public, max-age=14411, s-maxage=14411";
   remove beresp.http.Pragma;
   set beresp.ttl = 144000m;
   return(deliver);
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the actual site headers return proper ```Cache-Control``` which would make ```beresp.ttl``` positive? How did you know that Varnish is purging cached pages? Did you exhaust your cache storage? Complete VCL and returned headers would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`ttl` is a float internally, where 0 means the UNIX epoch. It can typically store up to 3.402823e+38 or thereabouts, which translates to somewhere in the region of 10^31 years, though with some loss of precision as you get far from epoch.

If pages are evicted from the cache, I'd look at them being removed ("LRU nuked" in `varnishstat`) instead.  You might also just want to write 100 days as "100d" rather than counting minutes.

Comment: Which values are valid? 7d for a week? Or 1w? Which dateformat shortcuts are allowed?

Comment: Docs (https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.2/reference/vcl.html#durations):
ms: milliseconds, s: seconds, m: minutes, h: hours, d: days, w: weeks, y: years

Comment: Thx @Tollef Fog Heen I didn't find that myself... I'm ashamed :-D